# Uploading '.xlsx' or '.docx' to SharePoint 2007 from ASP.NET app causing file 'corruption'

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, sharepoint, file-upload

I have an ASP.NET application wrapped in SharePoint 2007 website. Within this application I allow users to create requests and they can also upload supporting files for the request. When a user uploads supporting docs of type .docx or .xlsx (the only two that I have found to become corrupt so far) they are becoming 'corrupted' in a sense that when I attempt to open them, I'm prompted with a message saying:

"Excel found unreadable content in 'Book1.xlsx'. Do you want to recover the contents of this workbook? If you trust the source of this workbook, click Yes"

When I click yes, it does repair the file and display the contents correctly, but this is unacceptable to the users. I don't even want them to have the problem.

Here is the code (VB.NET) for my upload click event:

```
Private Sub Upload_Click(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles btnUpload.Click
Try
    Dim currentUser As SPUser = SPContext.Current.Web.AllUsers("SHAREPOINT\SYSTEM")
    Dim currentUserToken As SPUserToken = currentUser.UserToken
    Using currentSite As SPSite = New SPSite(SPContext.Current.Web.Url, currentUserToken)

        Using CurrentWeb As SPWeb = currentSite.OpenWeb
            CurrentWeb.AllowUnsafeUpdates = True

            Dim attachmentList As SPList = CurrentWeb.Lists("Requests")

            Dim item As SPListItem = attachmentList.GetItemById(CurrentRequestId)

            If FileUpload.PostedFile.ContentLength > Nothing And FileUpload.HasFile Then
                Dim fStream As Stream = FileUpload.PostedFile.InputStream
                Dim contents() As Byte = New Byte(fStream.Length) {}

                fStream.Read(contents, 0, CType(fStream.Length, Integer))
                fStream.Close()
                fStream.Dispose()

                Dim attachments As SPAttachmentCollection = item.Attachments
                Dim fileName As String = Path.GetFileName(FileUpload.PostedFile.FileName)
                attachments.Add(fileName, contents)
                item.Update()
            Else
                Page.ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(Page.GetType(), "disp_msg", "<script type='text/javascript'>alert('The file contains 0 Bytes of data and will be deleted.'); </script>")
            End If
        End Using
    End Using
    DisplayAttachment(CurrentRequestId)
    btnSave.Focus()
Catch ex As Exception
    Page.ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(Page.GetType(), "disp_msg", "<script type='text/javascript'>alert('Error Uploading File: " & ex.Message & "'); </script>")
End Try
End Sub
```

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Have you compared the two files to see what's different?

Comment: Basically to test this out, I created two excel files with Excel 2007 with the same content and different extensions, one with .xls and the other with .xlsx. When I view the .xls it works fine, when I view the .xlsx it's corrupted.

Comment: What I mean is, have you compared the original file (before uploading) with the corrupt copy of the file, using a binary file comparison tool to see which bytes in the file were changed?

Comment: Try flushing your fStream object, do believe I've read somewhere that not doing so can cause problems with the ending bytes in a file.

Comment: Using Windiff, the only difference I found was that the the uploaded file (that I downloaded) was newer than the original file that was uploaded.

Comment: @Orion, if the two files are exactly the same, either they are both corrupt, or neither is corrupt. In other words, based on the behavior you are seeing, there must be a difference between the good file and the bad file.

Comment: I have the same issue. I am using the SharePoint Object model to upload documents to SharePoint. When I try to open a docx or xlsx file, I get the same error. There is nothing wrong with the files because if I manually upload the document(s) in question, I am able to open them without the error. If I download the file that resides in the SharePoint document library and compare it to the original file, the sizes are different. The SharePoint document is 58 bytes larger than the original file.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem you have is in this line:

```
Dim contents() As Byte = New Byte(fStream.Length) {}
```

It should be

```
Dim contents() As Byte = New Byte(fStream.Length - 1) {}
```

The VB.NET arrays specify the upper bound - not the length - and since VB.NET is zero-based - the old line created one extra byte at the end.

This is typically not a problem, but docx and xlsx files are more sensitive to this extra byte.

Comment: You are absolutely correct. I actually figured this out a good while ago, but forgot to mark this as answered.